# The definition of `rand()` in GCC 9.3.0

Tags: c, gcc

I come to cross `rand()` in `C` and found `srand()` could only guarantee the reproducibility of the same machine but not the different platform.

As I already used my `srand(926)` and completed a quite time-consuming simulation, I like to find the definition of `rand()`. So that, I can get the same result on the different platforms as well.

Could someone point me in a direction to find the definition of `srand()` in `GCC 9.3.0`?

Thanks

Comment: GCC does not provide the definition. The definition is provided by the C standard library implementation which is not part of GCC. What OS/distribution are you on? Also beware that `rand` may potentially be a poor quality random number generator in which case you should verify that the simulation is not negatively affected by that.

Comment: Use the [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). This is portable to many systems, and should provide consistent results.

Comment: @user17732522, I really don't know that, any recommendation when choosing a random number generator?

Comment: Recommendation?
Knuth. Always Knuth.

Comment: @yuw444 The question I am asking is simply which operating system you are using. Windows? Linux? Mac? If Linux also which distribution. Ubuntu? Debian? Arch? etc. General library recommendation questions are off-topic, but there are many libraries implementing a variety of random number generators, for example the [GNU scientific library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/rng.html). (Beware that these are _not_ suitable for cryptographic purposes.)

Comment: @user17732522, it's the school's server, CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core).

Comment: @yuw444 CentOS uses (like most but not all Linux distributions) glibc as C standard library implementation. From what I can tell CentOS 7 should be using version 2.17 of glibc. You can browse the source in the git repository [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=stdlib;h=655a07341f55459622e57f34e0f2353e7c8da595;hb=c758a6861537815c759cba2018a3b1abb1943842). Look at the files `rand.c`, `random.c` and `random_r.c`. The version in the distribution might be slightly different if the distribution applies patches, but I don't think it should change anything significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc is a compiler and as such won't itself have an implementation. `srand` is part of the C standard library (libc), the implementation of which is probably glibc on your system.

The following will use the tip of the master branch for glibc at the time of writing. The version used on your system may be different.

`srand` is declared [here](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/b92a49359f33a461db080a33940d73f47c756126/stdlib/random.c#L216) as a weak symbol. Unless overridden, it'll invoke `__srandom_r` [here](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/b92a49359f33a461db080a33940d73f47c756126/stdlib/random.c#L211), which is defined [here](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/b92a49359f33a461db080a33940d73f47c756126/stdlib/random_r.c#L161). Both random.c and random_r.c appear to have ample documentation for how things work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a classic definition you can use for your purpose:

```
/* QuickC by Charlie Gordon 2014-2022 */

#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* 7.22.2 Pseudo-random sequence generation functions */

static unsigned long int next = 1;

/* 7.22.2.1 The rand function */
int rand(void) {
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next / 32768) % (RAND_MAX + 1);
}

/* 7.22.2.2 The srand function */
void srand(unsigned int seed) {
    next = seed;
}
```